# This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection, except when its okay

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am receiving this error only in testing. My build -prod works, the demo application project that consumes the built library can fully interact with all aspects of the parameters of the services in question. I use storybook and can see mock data loaded and no issue when running directly in the library with ivy. I am on angular 9.1.1. The tests are in jest, but this is not an issue elsewhere in the project.

I have a library that has 2 services derived from a base class. The base class itself does not have @Injectable decorator.

The test for one of the child services throws the error:

```
    This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid.
    This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.

    Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 0 is correct and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and its ancestors.
```

Strangely, the other service does not. Adding the @Injectable decorator requires that I also change the base class so that parameter 0 of all 3 classes is character-for-character identical. But upon doing this, I continue to get the error.

some snippets:

- base class

```
/** this base class exists because we provide a standard mock for the alerts service */
@Injectable()
export abstract class AlertsBase
  implements IPreloadingService, ICommonService {
  abstract serviceIdentifier: IConstructor<AlertsBase>
  isPreloaded: boolean
  delegate: ICachingService

  constructor (
    @Inject(CACHING_SERVICE_DELEGATE) cachingService: ICachingService
  ) {
    this.delegate = cachingService
  }
```

- passing class

```
/** exposed mock service (a demonstration) */
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MockAlertsService extends AlertsBase {
  serviceIdentifier = AlertsService

  constructor (
    @Inject(CACHING_SERVICE_DELEGATE) cachingService: ICachingService,
    @Inject(ALERTS_ENDPOINT) private endpoint: string,
    @Inject(MOCK_APP_ALERTS) private model: string
  ) {
    super(cachingService)

    console.debug('%c[MockAlertsService]', 'color: #f6b73c', 'constructor')
  }
```

- failing class

```
/** get alerts to display atop each page in alert components */
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlertsService extends AlertsBase {
  serviceIdentifier = AlertsService

  constructor (
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    @Inject(CACHING_SERVICE_DELEGATE) cachingService: ICachingService,
    @Inject(ALERTS_ENDPOINT) private endpoint: string
  ) {
    super(cachingService)

    console.debug('%c[AlertsService]', 'color: #f6b73c', 'constructor')
  }
```

Comment: This is just a guess: can you try moving the `HttpClient` parameter in the constructor of the `AlertsService` to be the last parameter?

Comment: post that as an answer! this was pattern blindness on my part .. I even mentioned in my OP that the first parameters were identical. But since that is not explicit in the error message, it is hard to notice!

Comment: Strange that worked! You would think the way you had it would be fine. I will post an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: it makes some sense, I've seen problems from the same in other typed languages.. I just got lost in the code .. since I had to change the signature (since I wasnt using the decorator, the base class could receive a raw object instead of a token), and that line was identical, I mistook its location in the child class

Comment: Interesting. I have never seen this error before. Guess I have just been lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `HttpClient` parameter in the constructor of the `AlertsService` to be the last parameter.

Order of the constructor parameters is important in the situation where the class extends another class.